# django haystack or sphinx for simple search?

Tags: python, django, search, sphinx, django-haystack

I am creating a food search.  I want to simply be able to type a food into a search box and have it return results.  I also want to be able to add priority to certain terms so that they show up.  For example, searching for "orange" would bring up the fruit first as opposed to the juice.

I haven't been able to determine the better search solution for this scenario in django.

Let me know which is the better solution for this scenario.

Comment: I would run for this Elasticsearch server and use it with django-haystack, which is actually a wrapper around search engine.

Comment: @NikolayBaluk are you recommending this solution because of my simple scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the current maintainer of [Django-SphinxQL](https://github.com/jorgecarleitao/django-sphinxql), an implementation for Sphinx in Django, and maintainer of the [Xapian backend](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/) for Haystack.

I recommend using Haystack:

- Haystack allows you to choose between different backends, support most standard features of search (e.g. highlight), and already stood the test of time on search engines for Django.
- Django-SphinxQL is in pre-alpha (other implementations such has [Django-Sphinx](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx) have stalled), and only support a minimal set of functionality.

The only reason I see to choose Sphinx search in detriment of Haystack (e.g. using Django-SphinxQL) is if you specifically have a use case where Sphinx is clearly superior to any Haystack backend.

For instance, Sphinx is known to be very fast indexing in the `plain` index, but it requires you to re-index everything when you update the database. This particular setup is very convenient for me because I'm using it to index a database that only changes once a day.

Comment: thank and I appreciate such an expert opinion.  I'm off to use haystack.

Comment: I believe Sphinx now supports real-time indexes.